# Improve the way suggested edit screen displays links

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

Currently it is hard to tell if a link has been added as a suggested edit.

This suggested edit I just came across had me scratching my head for a couple of minutes as this was the only edit provided.

Despite my stupidity, it would be good for any sized edit if the links were better highlighted.

Suggest maybe having blue text or another colour show through the green highlight.

[image]